# Serialize class with BsonDocument via JSON.NET or XML Serializer

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to return the following sample class by an ApiController, which is probably just JSON.NET serialized, but I want to avoid just converting the whole class to a json-string.

```
public class Report
{
    [BsonId, JsonIgnore]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public BsonDocument layout { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have looked at several ways but only one worked so far, which is creating a second class and map manually between the two by converting the layout-property to a json-string like this:

```
layout.ToJson();
```

This seems not very elegant and I'm wondering if there is a better way. None of the following ideas work for various reasons:

```
public class Report
{
    [BsonId, JsonIgnore]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public BsonDocument layout { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "layout")]
    public string layout2JSON()
    { 
        return layout.ToJson();
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class Report
{
    [BsonId, JsonIgnore]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public BsonDocument layout 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return layout.ToJson();
        }
        set; 
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to C# and might easily miss obvious answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're just looking to get layout as JSON correct? I'm not 100% I can see what output you're trying to achieve, but if so, your second code sample was already very close, try this;

```
public class Report
{ 
     [BsonId, JsonIgnore]
     public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

     public string name { get; set; }

     [JsonIgnore]
     private BsonDocument layout { get; set; }

     [BsonIgnore]
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "layout")]
     public string layout2JSON
     { 
         get { return layout.ToJson(); }
     }
}
```

Comment: Correct, I'm trying to get the whole object as json, but JSON.NET does not serialize a BsonDocument out-of-the-box and gives me an error. Your solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found I was able to return BSON documents directly from an Api Controller by returning them as IDictionaries.  You should be able to do something similar by declaring a layout property as an IDictionary.  This trick allows you to really easily get data in and out of MongoDB since there is also a BsonDocument constructor that takes an IDictionary.

```
    public IEnumerable<IDictionary> Get()
    {
        using (var mongo = new Mongo())
        {
            var collection = mongo.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Report");

            var cursor = collection.FindAll();
            cursor.SetFields(_summaryFields); 
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var doc in cursor)
            {
                i++;
                yield return doc.ToDictionary();
            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Your code only retrieves a list or an array, but not an unstructured object, right? Or is there a way to make Dictionary handle an unknown and unstructured object?

Comment: It handles an arbitrary BsonDocument as it is.  I pasted this from working code and my document has multiple levels of nesting including array child elements.  The BsonDocument.ToDictionary() performs a deep conversion to a dictionary hierarchy and the JSON.Net serializer properly emits JSON for this dictionary hierarchy.

Comment: It seems I got it working using type IDictionary<string, object> in the model and returning the layout object via .ToDictionary()  Thanks very much!